# como se calcula una precisión 0.0000001 = 1e-7o

Tags: javascript

Estoy solucionando problemas de programación y me dan el siguiente enunciado:

> La solución debe ser calculada con precisión 0.0000001 = 1e-7 o mejor.

¿A qué se refiere?

Mi código está en js.

Comment: Quizas se refiere ha que el resultado debe tener 7 digitos después del punto decimal.

Comment: exacto amigo, pero como verifico mi resultado cada vez que cambia ? con que propiedad o método?

Comment: podrias utilizar `.toFixed`

Answer (score 2):

Saludos en efecto como te comentaron se refiere al número de decimales despues de la coma o punto segun el caso para ello propongo esto:

```js
var precio = 1350
nuevoValor = parseFloat(precio).toFixed(7);
console.log(nuevoValor);
```

para mas detalle acerca de [toFixed JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)
Espero te sirva..!!